# Why inline styles returns [object Object] in React JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to set a inline css styles with a state check, but it returns `[object Object]`, how to make it work? I am new to React and do not really understand this return.

```
      <section
        className="header__banner"
        styles={scrolltop > height ? { marginBottom: `${margin}px` } : ""}
        ref={refHeaderBanner}
      >
```

Expect(e.g.): `styles="margin-bottom: 100px"`

Current: `styles=[object Object]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it's return an object because you worte the style between curly brackets, you need to write the style in this way

```
<section
      className="header__banner"
      style={scrolltop > height ? `margin-bottom: ${margin}px` : ""}
      ref={refHeaderBanner}
>
```

Comment: Now I have the expected result but not applying the margin. Should the value be between  quotation marks?

Answer (score 1):

styles={{scrolltop > height ?  marginBottom: `${margin}px` : ""}}
try this.

Answer (score 0):

HTML elements don't have a `styles` prop, so it gets converted to an expando-attribute which is a string (and which is ignored by everything except some hypothetical other JS you might write).

The prop you are looking for is `style` (singular) which does take an object as its value.